# Form not getting submitted in Selenium python

Tags: python, jsp, selenium, selenium-webdriver, phantomjs

```
<a class="button ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all ui-button-text-icon-primary" name="calculate" tabindex="56" href="#shipping_options" title="Ctrl + Enter" role="button" aria-disabled="false"><span class="ui-button-icon-primary ui-icon ui-icon-gear"></span><span class="ui-button-text">Search</span></a>
```

There is this button within a jsp form. I can not in any way submit the form using any uses of click(), submit(), send_keys(Keys.ENTER, Keys.CONTROL)

What can I possibly be doing wrong here. This is the link to the actual form [DHL Capability tool](https://dct.dhl.com/)

BTW I am using phantomjs.

Comment: Are you able to find the 'Search'  button successfully? Not certain but the sequence of keys in sendkeys() should be switched.

Comment: update your question with your phantomjs code.Just to see what you have tried.